# Redirect domain to other domains subdirectory but show first domain in address bar?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to redirect "abc.com" to "xyz.com/abc" but still, show "abc.com" in the browser's address bar. As far as I understand you'd be using rewrite rules to achieve this.

I own both domains and both pages are on the same server.

Its an ionos webserver. The website itself is located in

/clickandbuilds/mywebsite  (lets say this is "xyz.com")

Now there is a subpage on this website ("xyz.com/my-landing-page")

that is also accessible over its own domain (lets say "abc.com")

Right now im using a simple http redirect and all requests to "abc.com get redirected to "xyz.com/my-landing-page". This is the exact thing that I want but I do not want to show the url of the landing-page but the top-level-domain (xyz.

How would this condition look like?

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.5]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content\/cache\/(all|wpfc-mobile-cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your htaccess rule file in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: And also the info about your actual domain setup - which one points to which folder, etc.

Comment: Hi guys,

the htaccess file is pretty much emtpy, just a few entries form a wordpress cache plugin so far.

Comment: @d1ouh9d1, without seeing htaccess file and information asked by Cbroe it will be difficult to help here, so kindly do add detailed information in your question and let us know then, thank you.

Comment: I've updated my question with the requested information

Answer (score 1):

You have two obvious options, which one is better for you depends a bit on the specific situation:

1. an internal rewriting strategy:

You need to take care that the rewriting module is actually loaded into the http server. Then you can implement that rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc
RewriteRule ^ /abc%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]
```

This approach can be implemented in the actual http server's host configuration (which should be preferred) or in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") in case you do *not* have access to the real configuration (read: if you are using a cheap hosting provider).

2. an internal proxy strategy:

Instead of using the rewriting module you could directly use the proxy module:

```
ProxyPass / https://example.com/abc/
ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com/abc/
```

This needs to be implemented in the actual http server's host configuration, however. So you'd need access to that.

The same could be achieved using the rewriting module (which uses the proxy module internally). This would allow to use distributed configuration file (".htaccess") for this approach too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/abc%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Both proxy based options share the disadvantage that performance is an issue due to the fact that you need a full additional internal http request for each and every incoming request.

---

In general the first approach makes more sense, out of performance reasons. This has to be supported by your application logic however: this will only work if your application uses relative references ("links"). If it uses absolute URLs instead and you cannot change that you will need to dive into the second approach.